# disable nagios apache monitoring and amanda client

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall, amanda

I´ve cloned a Ubunutu 12.04 virtual Server. The original server uses Nagios for apache monitoring and amanda client for backups. On the clone I want disable both services. Whats the best way for this? (Someone else did the install, never used one of them)

```
dpkg -l | grep nagios
dpkg -l | grep amanda
```

Gives me

```
ii  he-nagios                       0.5-4                             Host Europe Nagios Package
ii  nagios-plugins                  1.4.15-5ubuntu3.2                 Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems (metapackage)
ii  nagios-plugins-basic            1.4.15-5ubuntu3.2                 Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems
ii  nagios-plugins-standard         1.4.15-5ubuntu3.2                 Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems
ii  he-amanda-client                1.0-1                             Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver (Client)
ii  he-amanda-common                1.0-1                             Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver (Libs)
ii  he-amanda-restore               1.0-1                             Restoretool for he-amanda-client
```

Will f.e.

```
apt-get --purge remove he-nagios
```

do the job?

Kind regards, 
t book

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the packages:

```
apt-get remove <package-name>
```

Note that if you add the option `--purge` you will also remove the config files.

Comment: thanks, is the nagios plugin somewhere included within the apache modules? in other words do I have to disable some apache modul first?

Comment: no, they are not in the apache modules

Comment: if apache has been used as a web server for nagios, you can also remove the configuration for the Nagios website that you should find in this folder: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/